# Why are my model's clothes collapsing in on itself?

Tags: mesh, cloth-simulation

I've just finished doing some animations for my model for my Unity game and I noticed that on the top, it sort of collapses on itself (see screenshot provided) and I'm not sure why it's doing this.

[image: Property of CraftyMaelyss]

I had a look around and everyone talks about how the model's clothes clip through the body but not the clothes itself.

The top only has 1 layer, it's not a box shape but I believe I have used one of the modifiers to change the thickness of the material(I was following an online tutorial but removed the cloth simulation due to it causing more errors then it was worth but even after removing the cloth simulation, the material kept the same thickness)

If screenshots could be included with any helpful advice, it would be greatly appreciated as I still consider myself a novice when it comes to blender :)

Also please note that due to this model appearing in an upcoming game, I cannot share or upload the model, sorry.

Comment: Can you confirm that we see here the inner part of a rigged cloth which has thickness?

Comment: Please be descriptive about what the image shows (you can edit your question using the [edit] link below it) or upload a clearer image. It is difficult to tell which part of the image is clothing and which is the underlying model.

Comment: Sorry, I realise I uploaded the wrong screenshot D: It's been updated with the proper screenshot that I meant to originally use.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to remove the inner faces of the clothing model, since they should never be seen when worn on a character. In game development, its in your best interest to exclude any faces of a model that will never be seen, so you don't bog down your frame rate with excess geometry.

If you absolutely must keep the inner faces of cloth on your character for whatever reason, then your issue exists in the outer vertices of the cloth having more or less influence than the inner vertices. You'll want to improve your vertex weights to accomodate the thin thickness of the cloth.